# How to retrieve name and type from org.apache.spark.sql.Column?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How do I retrieve name and type from org.apache.spark.sql.Column? There are no fields for that at all.

Comment: sorry, I dont think i understand your question. could you provide sample input/output or explain the need?

Comment: I have a org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame and org.apache.spark.sql.Column. I want to find the name of the column and its type from this data

Comment: you have multiple options, try to play around with `df.columns`, `df.schema` or `df.dtypes`

Answer (score 0):

I would try df.printSchema().
It should print the Column name along with their types.

`df` refers to the name of the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, I normally query the schema:

```
val c: Column = ??? // e.g. df("id")

val dataType = df.select(c).schema.head.dataType.simpleString
val name = df.select(c).schema.head.name
```

but you can also try investigating the underlying expression (attribute must be resolved to do this)

```
val simpleString = c.expr.simpleString) // gives name and type
val dataType = c.expr.dataType.simpleString)
```